# How to read Encrypted Excel using OLEDB in .Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to query an Encrypted Excel file using OLEDB, but having some issues
What i am doing is first opening the file by supplying the password
Opening the connection string with the path of the Excel file
Querying the Excel file (Select * from [Sheet1$])
Everything is workig fine if there are no other excel instances open in the machine.
But if there are any other Excel file is open then when i open the Connection i am getting password prompt and not able to proceed with querying..

Please help me if you have any other ideas in reading the Excel by OLEDB
**I dont want to change the reading of Excel from OLEDB to Excel API's**